# Pyrit - can you set order passwords are checked?

Tags: wireless-networking, security, backtrack, wpa

Lets say I have captured some handshakes and other data from a WPA network and would like to crack it using Pyrit. I have a database of around 800 million passwords, but having Pyrit check through all of these using attack_batch takes weeks or longer on my PC.

Is there any way of telling Pyrit to check a certain list first? As in have Pyrit check a list of, say, the 10,000 most common passwords BEFORE trying my large database? Is it as simple as importing the smaller, common password list first?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, Pyrit goes through each word in order, so it should be as simple as moving the common words to the top.

Assuming that **top.txt** is a file holding all the words you want to try first and **words.txt** is your main wordlist, this should do the trick:

```
cat top.txt | cat words.txt > new_list.txt
pyrit -r wpa.cap -i new_list.txt -b <BSSID> attack_passthrough
```